# spring batch Unable to deserialize the execution context

Tags: java, spring, jackson, spring-batch

When i ran my spring batch, it ran properly with out any serialize errors. But batch job failed at nested step **step_1_1_1** with run time error.

When i try to re-start the same batch job it is failing to start with below error. I got the error at **job_1** at **step_1**.

I really do not understand why it is failing to deserialize the **BATCH_STEP_EXECUTION_CONTEXT** of its context.

```
    ERROR [main] (AbstractJob.java:337) - Encountered fatal error executing job
    org.springframework.batch.core.JobExecutionException: Flow execution ended unexpectedly
        at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.FlowJob.doExecute(FlowJob.java:142)
        at org.springframework.batch.core.job.AbstractJob.execute(AbstractJob.java:308)
        at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher$1.run(SimpleJobLauncher.java:141)
        at org.springframework.core.task.SyncTaskExecutor.execute(SyncTaskExecutor.java:50)
        at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher.run(SimpleJobLauncher.java:134)
        at com.fhlbof.duedate.BatchProcess.start(BatchProcess.java:52)
        at com.fhlbof.duedate.DSSBatchDriver.main(DSSBatchDriver.java:32)
    Caused by: org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.FlowExecutionException: Ended flow=batchProcessJob at state=batchProcessJob.dailyStreamProcess with exception
        at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.SimpleFlow.resume(SimpleFlow.java:178)
        at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.SimpleFlow.start(SimpleFlow.java:144)
        at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.FlowJob.doExecute(FlowJob.java:136)
        ... 6 more
    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to deserialize the execution context
        at org.springframework.batch.core.repository.dao.JdbcExecutionContextDao$ExecutionContextRowMapper.mapRow(JdbcExecutionContextDao.java:325)
        at org.springframework.batch.core.repository.dao.JdbcExecutionContextDao$ExecutionContextRowMapper.mapRow(JdbcExecutionContextDao.java:309)
        at org.springframework.jdbc.core.RowMapperResultSetExtractor.extractData(RowMapperResultSetExtractor.java:93)
        at org.springframework.jdbc.core.RowMapperResultSetExtractor.extractData(RowMapperResultSetExtractor.java:60)
        at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate$1.doInPreparedStatement(JdbcTemplate.java:667)
        at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:605)
        at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:657)
        at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:688)
        at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:700)
        at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:756)
        at org.springframework.batch.core.repository.dao.JdbcExecutionContextDao.getExecutionContext(JdbcExecutionContextDao.java:127)
        at org.springframework.batch.core.repository.support.SimpleJobRepository.getLastStepExecution(SimpleJobRepository.java:247)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:338)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:197)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:294)
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:98)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy5.getLastStepExecution(Unknown Source)
        at org.springframework.batch.core.job.SimpleStepHandler.handleStep(SimpleStepHandler.java:115)
        at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.JobFlowExecutor.executeStep(JobFlowExecutor.java:66)
        at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.state.StepState.handle(StepState.java:67)
        at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.SimpleFlow.resume(SimpleFlow.java:169)
        ... 8 more
    Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot construct instance of `org.springframework.batch.core.JobParameter` (although at least one Creator exists): cannot deserialize from Object value (no delegate- or property-based Creator)
     at [Source: (ByteArrayInputStream); line: 1, column: 166] (through reference chain: java.util.HashMap["org.springframework.batch.core.step.job.JobStep.JOB_PARAMETERS"]->org.springframework.batch.core.JobParameters["parameters"]->java.util.LinkedHashMap["xxxx"])
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException.from(MismatchedInputException.java:63)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.reportInputMismatch(DeserializationContext.java:1342)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.handleMissingInstantiator(DeserializationContext.java:1031)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializerBase.deserializeFromObjectUsingNonDefault(BeanDeserializerBase.java:1275)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserializeFromObject(BeanDeserializer.java:325)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:159)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.MapDeserializer._readAndBindStringKeyMap(MapDeserializer.java:527)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.MapDeserializer.deserialize(MapDeserializer.java:364)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.MapDeserializer.deserialize(MapDeserializer.java:29)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.jsontype.impl.AsArrayTypeDeserializer._deserialize(AsArrayTypeDeserializer.java:116)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.jsontype.impl.AsArrayTypeDeserializer.deserializeTypedFromObject(AsArrayTypeDeserializer.java:61)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.MapDeserializer.deserializeWithType(MapDeserializer.java:400)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.impl.FieldProperty.deserializeAndSet(FieldProperty.java:138)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserializeFromObject(BeanDeserializer.java:368)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:159)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.jsontype.impl.AsArrayTypeDeserializer._deserialize(AsArrayTypeDeserializer.java:116)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.jsontype.impl.AsArrayTypeDeserializer.deserializeTypedFromAny(AsArrayTypeDeserializer.java:71)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.UntypedObjectDeserializer$Vanilla.deserializeWithType(UntypedObjectDeserializer.java:712)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.MapDeserializer._readAndBindStringKeyMap(MapDeserializer.java:529)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.MapDeserializer.deserialize(MapDeserializer.java:364)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.MapDeserializer.deserialize(MapDeserializer.java:29)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:4001)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:3065)
        at org.springframework.batch.core.repository.dao.Jackson2ExecutionContextStringSerializer.deserialize(Jackson2ExecutionContextStringSerializer.java:59)
        at org.springframework.batch.core.repository.dao.Jackson2ExecutionContextStringSerializer.deserialize(Jackson2ExecutionContextStringSerializer.java:40)
        at org.springframework.batch.core.repository.dao.JdbcExecutionContextDao$ExecutionContextRowMapper.mapRow(JdbcExecutionContextDao.java:322)
        ... 35 more
```

The jobs configuration looks like the below.

```
<job id="job_1">
    <step id = "Step_1">
        <job ref="job_1_1" job-launcher="jobLauncher"/>
    </step>
</job>

<job id="job_1_1">
    <step id="step_1_1">
        <job ref="job_1_1_1" job-launcher="jobLauncher"/>
        <next on="COMPLETED" to="step_1_2"/>
        <fail on="*" exit-code="FAILED"/>
    </step>
    <step id="step_1_2">
        <job ref="job_1_1_2" job-launcher="jobLauncher"/>
        <fail on="FAILED" exit-code="FAILED"/>      
    </step>     
</job>

<job id="job_1_1_1">    
    <step id="step_1_1_1" >
        <tasklet ref="task_1_1_1_1"/>
        <next on ="COMPLETED" to ="step_1_1_2" />
        <fail on ="*" exit-code="FAILED" />
    </step>        
     <step id="step_1_1_2">
        <tasklet ref="task_1_1_1_2"/>
    </step>
</job>

<job id="job_1_1_2">
    <step id="step_1_1_2_1">
        <tasklet ref="task_1_1_2_1"/>
        <next on ="COMPLETED" to ="step_1_1_2_2" />
        <fail on ="*" exit-code="FAILED" />
    </step>
    <step id="step_1_1_2_2">
        <tasklet ref="task_1_1_2_2"/>
    </step>
</job>
```

The dependencies which i am using are listed below.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>sybase</groupId>
    <artifactId>jconn3</artifactId>
    <version>6.05-26732</version>
</dependency>        
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.batch</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-batch-core</artifactId>
  <version>4.0.0.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
 <dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
    <version>1.7.25</version>
</dependency>      
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
    <version>5.0.2.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>           
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
  <version>5.0.2.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
    <version>1.4</version>
</dependency>       
<dependency>
  <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
  <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
  <version>2.6.0.redhat-4</version>
</dependency>       
<dependency>
  <groupId>junit</groupId>
  <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
  <version>4.12</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Did you able to solve this issue ?